# Classify column on the basis of sequence and patterns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a column `Id` in a PostgreSQL table `ABC`.

`Id` is a `bigint` of length 10 `(minLength=maxLength=10)`

I have to write a SQL query and classify `Id` as:

- Any Id that commences with exactly 3 consecutive odd digits and concludes with at least 2 consecutive even digits is classified as “TYPE A”;
- Any Id where the second digit is greater than 6 or the third character is less than or equal to 4 is classified as “TYPE B”;
- Any odd-numbered Id is classified as “TYPE C” unless it ends in 7;
- Any even-numbered Id is classified as “TYPE D” unless it ends in 2;
- All other Id are classified as “TYPE X”;

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each type can be found with a regular expression.

> ```
> create table ABC (
>  Id decimal(10) primary key check(length(Id::text)=10)
> );
>
> insert into ABC (Id) values
>   (1350000042)
> , (1640000000)
> , (1090000503)
> , (1294567890)
> , (1090000907)
> , (1090000902)
> ```

> ```
> /*
> Type A: Any Id that commences with exactly 3 consecutive odd digits
>         and concludes with at least 2 consecutive even digits;
> Type B: Any Id where the second digit is greater than 6 
>         or the third character is less than or equal to 4;
> Type C: Any odd-numbered Id unless it ends in 7;
> Type D: Any even-numbered Id unless it ends in 2;
> Type X: All other Id;
> */
> select Id
> , case
>   when Id::text ~ '^[13579]{3}[02468].*[02468]{2}$' then 'A'
>   when Id::text ~ '^(.[7-9]|..[0-4])' then 'B'
>   when Id::text ~ '[1359]$' then 'C'
>   when Id::text ~ '[0468]$' then 'D'
>   else 'X'
>   end as Type
> from ABC
> order by Type
> ```
>
> ```
>         id | type
> ---------: | :---
> 1350000042 | A   
> 1760000000 | B   
> 1640000000 | B   
> 1090000503 | C   
> 1294567890 | D   
> 1090000907 | X   
> 1090000902 | X
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=eafdc49ae600e00e93129e113eaafc4b)*